# Windows Phone Dropdown

Tags: windows-phone-7

I see that there is not a dropdown/combobox offered in the windows phone toolbox. I can see that there has to be a way to create one because in the settings of the phone, choosing a theme is essentially a dropdown menu.

Does anyone know where I can get sample code how to create one? I have seen a few samples, but the xaml seems really long and complicated. Is it really that difficult to create this control?

Comment: Silverlight for Windows Phone does have a Combobox control.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291) (You really should be using this).  The ListPicker Control will do what you want.

Here is an in-depth tutorial on how to use it: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth

Here is a description of it (from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2010/11/16/autocompletebox-listpicker-longlistselector-pagetransitions-for-wp7-oh-my-november-2010-wp7-toolkit-release.aspx)):

> ListPicker
>
> Comboboxes just aren't cool in WP7
>   dev. So use the ListPicker instead.
>   Two formats available. The first
>   expands in place to give you options.
>   Useful for short lists. The second
>   takes you over to another page witha
>   full listbox to choose from then
>   returns to the calling screen. You can
>   see this in use on WP7 when you change
>   Settings / Ringtones & Sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a theme is actually creating a new page, and on selecting a color, it navigates back to the previous page with that value.

This is how I do this:

```
private void modelListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //if SelectedIndex == -1, do nothing
    if(modelListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;

    //navigate to the MainPage
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri
        (String.Format("/views/MainPage.xaml?MakeIndex={0}&ModelIndex={1}", m_nCameraDataIndex, modelListBox.SelectedIndex),
        UriKind.Relative));

    //reset SelectedIndex
    modelListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
} //end method modelListBox_SelectionChanged
```

For a ddlist, I found this:

http://www.simego.com/Blog/2008/05/combobox-dropdo